# how to get data from this result of query in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have written this query and i want access my user email.
The query is

```
 $records =  $this->projectRepository->with(['customer','provider'])->all();
        dd($records);
        foreach($records as $record) {
            dd($record->provider->User->email);


        }
```

the result of my dd($records) is as given below.i want to access highligted part.So let me know the for each loop.Whats mistake in my for each loop.I 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga8pv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your `provider` relation returns an instance of your `User` model. So your `provider` and `User` are one and the same here. You can access the `email` attribute (or any other `User` attribute) like this:

```
$records = $this->projectRepository
                ->with(['customer','provider'])
                ->all();

foreach($records as $record):
    // The user email
    echo $record->provider->email;

    // The user name
    echo $record->provider->name;
endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give us more to work with next time. Give us an error. Give us your models. Give us something!

Now, from what I see, you need to remove the User, as the provider is of class User according to your provided dd screenshot. Thus, `$record->provider->email` should do the trick. Let me know if this works.